# Checkbox in Listview gets focused when pressed

Tags: android, android-widget

Must be simple, but I couldn't figure it out.
I have a listview with custom list item view which contains a checkbox.
When I press one item (not the checkbox), the checkbox got highlighted.
Checkbox focusable property is false.
How can I simply prevent the highlight when the select an item in the listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, to answer my own question.
It's seems that it's not possible to achieve this with the built in android checkbox control.
I have to use my own custom checkbox images for this and define the only the on and off states in the concerning style.

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the problem that list row cannot be focused.

That is a scenario in my articles solving ListView not responding problem: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/listview-doesnt-respond-to-onitemclicklistener/

Comment: That answer is completely irrelevant. What are you trying to tell me?